# datepicker not showing year and month dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

i have a website done in codeigniter PHP, I have some form modals which asks date to the user,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#own_design_party_date').datepicker();
 $('#corporate_party_date').datepicker();
 $('#fabbutton').draggable();
});
```

the date field is not showing dropdown for selecting month and year

[image]

this is my live URL : [enter link description here](https://www.booktheparty.in/)
can anyone please tell me how to fix it, thanks in advance

Comment: According to Datepicker docs you should provide `changeMonth` and `changeYear` parameters while initializing datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Comment: @MaryjaPiaredryj i have like 5-6 forms with date, is there anyways to do like a one line of code for all the datepickers

Comment: Sure, either just add same class to all the datepickers and call them like `$('.js-datepicker').datepicker(...)` of save general config to one variable and pass it everywhere you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example of datepicker you can use this

```js
var newdate=$("#selected").val();
function getdate() {

console.log(newdate)
 $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '-3M',
            maxDate: '+60D',
        });
    }
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("refresh");
    getdate()
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>



</div><!-- End demo -->
```